# Does the Heart Require Gold?

Tags: cardiology

I distinctly remember an episode of *NOVA* from the early 1980’s that concerned itself with gold. One of the points that was made was that there are trace amounts of gold in the human body, specifically in the heart, and without this gold our hearts wouldn't beat. I've never been able to find another citation of this. Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.webelements.com/gold/biology.html) source, gold is not a necessary trace element for living organisms.

Would have been cool, though...